# Swap last two characters in a string, make it lowercase, and add a space

Tags: python, swap

I'm trying to take the last two letters of a string, swap them, make them lowercase, and leave a space in the middle. For some reason the output gives me white space before the word.

For example if input was APPLE then the out put should be e l

It would be nice to also be nice to ignore non string characters so if the word was App3e then the output would be e p

```
def last_Letters(word):
    
    last_two = word[-2:]
    swap = last_two[-1:] + last_two[:1]
    
    for i in swap:
        if i.isupper():
            swap = swap.lower()
    
        return swap[0]+ " " +swap[1]
    
    
word = input(" ")
print(last_Letters(word))
```

Comment: If you run this script and enter `APPLE`, it outputs `e l` - which I think is what you say you want. Please provide an example of input and output that demonstrate the problem you're having. Note that there's far simpler ways to achieve what you're doing. And that you need to be more specific about your other requirements: what if there are more numbers? What if the string doesn't contain letters at all? What about a string that's only one character long? Etc.

Comment: The `input()` function prints the string passed to it. Since you use: `input(" ")` it first prints a space, then prints the input, so you get `" APPLE"`. Is that the space you are talking about? If so, just use `word = input()`.

Comment: Grismar You're right, I was going crazy because I thought I was doing it right, but the assignment software kept saying it was incorrect. Mark mentioned I needed to take the space out of my input str and it worked. Thank you both!

Comment: Simpler function for comparison : `def last_letters(word): return ' '.join([c.lower() for c in word if c.isalpha()][-2:][::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following function:

```
import re

def last_Letters(word):
    letters = re.sub(r'\d', '', word)
    if len(letters) > 1:
        return letters[-1].lower() + ' ' + letters[-2].lower()
    return None
```

It follows these steps:

- removes all the digits
- if there are at least two characters:

  - lowers every character
  - builds the required string by concatenation of the nth letter, a space and the nth-1 letter
  - and returns the string
- returns "*None*"

Answer (score 0):

Since I said there was a simpler way, here's what I would write:

```
text = input()
result = ' '.join(reversed([ch.lower() for ch in text if ch.isalpha()][-2:]))
print(result)
```

How this works:

- `[ch.lower() for ch in text]` creates a list of lowercase characters from some iterable `text`
- adding  `if ch.isalpha()` filters out anything that isn't an alphabetical character
- adding `[-2:]` selects the last two from the preceding sequence
- and `reversed()` takes the sequence and returns an iterable with the elements in reverse
- `' '.join(some_iterable)` will join the characters in the iterable together with spaces in between.

So, `result` is set to be the last two characters of all of the alphabetical characters in `text`, in reverse order, separated by a space.

Part of what makes Python so powerful and popular, is that once you learn to read the syntax, the code very naturally tells you exactly what it is doing. If you read out the statement, it is self-describing.